# Issue in compiling this open source application

Tags: c++, build, librecad

I am trying to set up and run [**LibreCAD**](http://librecad.org/cms/home.html) and I am following their [Build From Source Guide](http://wiki.librecad.org/index.php/LibreCAD_Installation_from_Source).

At some point, and after installing [QT](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-support.html) and [boost](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_61_0.html), I reach the step where it says this:

> To change these default settings you have to create the file
>   scripts/custom-windows.bat and overwrite the different settings
>   without effect to the SCM (git). Example for
>   scripts/custom-windows.bat:
>
> ```
>    set Qt_DIR=C:\Qt\5.4
>    set NSIS_DIR=C:\PROGRA~2\NSIS
>    set MINGW_VER=mingw491_32
> ```

So I created a `custom-windows.bat` file and overwrote the settings. Now, and since I am working on 64 bit Windows, They are saying that I need to do this:

> There are issues with the NSIS_DIR path on 64 Bit Windows. When NSIS
>   is installed in the Program Files (x86) folder and NSIS_DIR is added
>   to the PATH, something goes wrong in the build process.
>
> **In this case use the command dir /X \ and get an output like this:**
>
> ```
>    09/02/2014  09:50 PM    <DIR>          PROGRA~1     Program Files
>    10/27/2014  12:33 PM    <DIR>          PROGRA~2     Program Files (x86)
>    08/16/2014  10:49 PM    <DIR>          Qt
> ```

But what does that mean? "*..use the command `dir /X \` and get the output..*" Where and how? Appreciate it if anyone could tell me how to solve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up a command prompt and literally type `dir /X \`. The output will show the mapping between the short folder names and the long ones.

Your goal is to use the correct short form representation for `Program Files (x86)` in `NSIS_DIR`, since it's not always `PROGRA~2`. It can vary from filesystem to filesystem, based on the history of the filesystem.